# How to compare a list of vectors to find whether they contain common elements?

Tags: r

I have a list of vectors, with variable lengths. I want to know, for all pairwise vectors, do they contain common information? Below is an example:

The list x has three vectors, a, b, and c. a and c both contain 1, so this comparison should return true. No other comparison should return true. I have tried the following solutions. I thought that outer would be the best approach to this problem, but it currently returns true for all comparisons, which is not my expected result.

```
xx = list(a = 1,
          b = c(2, 3),
          c = c(1, 4, 6))

outer(xx, xx, "%in%")

outer(xx, xx, function(x, y) x %in% y)

func2 = function(x, y){z = cbind(x, y); z[,1] %in% z[,2]}
outer(xx, xx, func2)


Map("%in%", xx, xx)
```

Expected result:

```
   a,  b,  c
a, T,  F,  T
b, F,  T,  F
c, T,  F,  T
```

Comment: Why not use `intersect`?

Answer (score 2):

I figured this out - although I don't understand the logic behind this solution.

It appears that wrapping the function in Vectorize provides the expected output.

```
func3 = function(x, y){any(x %in% y)}
outer(xx, xx, Vectorize(func3))
```

Comment: `outer` is a bit tricky - `outer(1:4, 1:3)` doesn't do `1 * 1` then `1 * 2` etc separately, it does something like `rep(1:4, rep(length(1:3), length(1:4))) * 1:3` where each input is repeated to match up in length to the other, and *only then* the vectorized function is applied. If you want the piece-by-piece calculation to occur instead, `Vectorize` will take care of that.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @thelatemail, much clearer. An odd function!